# fs_usage tool: How to output *full* pathnames

Tags: macos, bash, filesystems

I'm using fs_usage on Mac to dump my app's file accesses to a text file. The only problem is that only a truncated version of the path is output. This is pointed out in the man page, but there appears to be no option to show the full file paths in the output (at least when I redirect it to a file: I've run it purely in the terminal and it output proper paths). I have a lot of directory structures in which the final few path components look very similar, but they are from different parent directories.

Comment: I was looking for this same option, it appears the space given to the path is based on the width of the terminal (at least for me) without any option directly in the tool perhaps there is a way to trick the terminal into thinking its width is really big prior to capturing the output-- that is what I'm looking into now.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that fs_usage is limited to ~253 characters of output, suggesting that it may be hardcoded with hardcoded 255 or 256 char limit.

The GUI tool *fseventer* does not suffer such a limit, you may also try *fslogger*.

fseventer - http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start

fslogger - [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200502165655/http://osxbook.com/software/fslogger/)

Answer (score 0):

`fs_usage -w` seems to work well for me.

from the man page:

> -w      Specifying the -w option forces a wider, more detailed output, regardless of the window size.

Redirecting to a file works. I've only tested this on OSX 10.8 and 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

At least on macOS 10.11.6 `fs_usage -w` still gives me ~250 characters lines (of which chars 57-222 devoted to paths) even if redirected to a file.
I tried running it under Terminal, iTerm2 and Alacritty, all with insanely small fonts (to achieve a wider screen size) in the hope it could be somehow caused by the terminal emulator (improbable but why not), to no avail.
I second the assumption that the line length is hardcoded, perhaps for speed.

EDIT: from [fs_usage.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-880.60.2/fs_usage.tproj/fs_usage.c.auto.html):

```
/*
 * MAXCOLS controls when extra data kicks in.
 * MAX_WIDE_MODE_COLS controls -w mode to get even wider data in path.
 */
#define MAXCOLS 132
#define MAX_WIDE_MODE_COLS 264
#define MAXWIDTH MAX_WIDE_MODE_COLS + 64
```

Comment: For anyone reading about fseventer and fslogger, they're both gone. I found them on archive.org, fseventer has a notice that "10.10 Yosemite is classified as unsupported till further notice -- Last usable os is osx 10.9 Mavericks (Oct 2013)", fslogger has a notice that "The interface that fslogger uses is private to Apple. [...] FSLogger-1.1.dmg (only for Mac OS X 10.4.x "Tiger") [...] FSLogger-2.1.dmg (only for Mac OS X 10.5.x "Leopard")".